# Titan DB on AWS Dynamo slow queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, titan

Was wondering why the following queries were slow using the comic db example:

g.V.has('weapon', 'ring')

// I added this vertex to see if a result size of one would be faster.
g.V.has('weapon', 'asdf')

while a query like g.V.has('comic-book', 'AVF 4') is fast?

Comment: Is the property 'weapon' indexed? If not, the query will do a full scan.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Kuppitz is correct. You or I could submit a pull request to the project to index the [weapon attribute](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/src/main/java/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory.java#L82).